# Get Items in ListView Windows Phone

Tags: listview, uwp

I wanted to get items selected in my listview. Every time I select item in my list view it always gets the last item. Here's my code:

**XAML**

[image]

**Code Behind**

[image]

Appreciate your help, thank you.

Updated:

Person Class

```
   private string name;
        private string imagePath;
        private string contact;
        private string gender;

        public Person()
        {

        }

        public String Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
            }

        }

        public String Gender
        {
            get { return gender; }
            set
            {
                gender = value;
            }

        }

        public String ImagePath
        {
            get { return imagePath; }
            set
            {
                imagePath = value;
            }
        }

        public String Contact
        {
            get { return contact; }
            set
            {
                contact = value;
            }
        }
```

MainPage.cs

```
 Person person = new Person();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        person.Name = textBoxName.Text.ToString();
        person.Contact = textBoxContact.Text.ToString();
        listViewDirectory.Items.Add(person);

        textBoxName.Text = "";
        textBoxContact.Text = "";
        radioButtonMale.IsChecked = false;
        radioButtonFemale.IsChecked = false;
        imageGender.Source = null;
    }

    private void radioButtonIsClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedRadio = myStackPanel.Children.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.IsChecked == true);

        if (selectedRadio.Content.ToString().Equals("Male"))
        {
            imageGender.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(
       "ms-appx:///Assets/tiles/boy.png", UriKind.Absolute));
            person.ImagePath = "ms-appx:///Assets/tiles/boy.png";
            person.Gender = selectedRadio.Tag.ToString();
        }
        else if (selectedRadio.Content.ToString().Equals("Female"))
        {
            imageGender.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(
       "ms-appx:///Assets/tiles/girl.png", UriKind.Absolute));
            person.ImagePath = "ms-appx:///Assets/tiles/girl.png";
            person.Gender = selectedRadio.Tag.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void listViewDirectory_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Person obj = (Person)e.ClickedItem;

        Debug.WriteLine(obj.Name);


    }
```

Comment: Please copy/paste your code and format it using SO tag editor.

Comment: Are you try to remove all scrollviewer properties at ListView? May be it cause problem

Comment: @HelloWindowsPhone: No, I need to get the values from the listview whenever I click the item. But, I always get the last value from the listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mindOfAi said, you should be able to use the `ItemClick` event.It occurs when an item in the list view receives an interaction, and the IsItemClickEnabled property is true. And we can get item by the [`ItemClickEventArgs.ClickedItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemClickEventArgs#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemClickEventArgs_ClickedItem) property.

From the code that you posted, it seems you define a person instance, and set the data by the buttonAdd_Click event. We can not find where do you set the [`Itemsource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ItemsControl_ItemsSource) of the `ListView`.

You should be able to add your person object to the collection, and we can set the collection to the `Itemsource`. Then we can get the `ClickedItem` by the `ItemClick` event.

For example:

```
private ObservableCollection<Person> Persons;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
    Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Persons.Add(new Person());
        Persons[i].Contact = "Contact" + i;
        Persons[i].Gender = "Gender" + i;
        Persons[i].ImagePath = "ms - appx:///Assets/tiles/boy.png";
        Persons[i].Name = "Name" + i;
    }
    listViewDirectory.ItemsSource = Persons;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jayden Gu - MSFT. I added ObservableCollection in my code and it solves my problem. Cheers (Y)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend this. Don't use ListView's `Tapped` event for item selection. Why not use just `ItemClick` event?

First, enable your `ListView`'s `IsItemClickEnabled` on your `XAML`. Set it from false to true. Then add the `ItemClick` event.

```
private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
   //Use e.ClickedItem to get the data;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @mindOfAi. I already tried that but still get's the last item in listview.

Comment: That's odd. Did you remove the `Tapped` event after adding the `ItemClick`?

Comment: Yes, I already removed it. I'm not sure why it always give last item in my listview :(

Comment: Can you also share your data? Thanks. I don't see any problem with your code tbh (if you already changed it to `ItemClick`.