# Get item in listview using RightTapped in Windows Phone

Tags: listview, uwp

I already know how to get item in listview using ItemClick event. 
See this thread: [Get Items in ListView Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477285/get-items-in-listview-windows-phone)

Now, I also wanted to get the item in my listview using RightTapped.

Appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [`RightTapped`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_RightTapped) event you can receive [`RightTappedRoutedEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.righttappedroutedeventargs)  object. From this you can get the right tapped [`ListViewItemPresenter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.listviewitempresenter) and you should be able get the item by its [`DataContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_DataContext). Code as follows:

```
private void listViewDirectory_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItemPresenter itempresenter = e.OriginalSource as ListViewItemPresenter;
    Person obj = (Person)itempresenter.DataContext;         
    Debug.WriteLine(obj.Name);
}
```

If you don't want use `ListViewItemPresenter`, `FrameworkElement` also worked.

```
FrameworkElement itempresenter = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;   
Person obj = (Person)itempresenter.DataContext;   
Debug.WriteLine(obj.Name);
```

Comment: Hi @Sunteen Wu: I can't use ListViewItemPresenter as it might not beavailable in Windows Phone. :(

Comment: @AppDev I tried `ListViewItemPresenter` on the mobile 10586 emulater, it can work well. If you don't want to use , a `FrameworkElement` also can work. I updated the reply to add code by using `FrameworkElement`.

Comment: Wu: It works! I used FrameworkElement. Appeciate your help, thanks :)